# How to optimize models.objects.all()

Tags: python, database, django-models

views

```
def vms(request):
user = request.user
servers = List.objects.all()
return render_to_response(
    'vmserver/all_vms.html', {
        'list': servers,
        'user': user,
    }
)
```

template

```
{% for vm in list %}
     <tr class="odd gradeX">
     <td><a href="/vmserver/vms/{{ vm.id }}/$">{{ vm.list_name }}</a></td>
     <td>{{ vm.ip }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.app_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.cpu }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.mem }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.total_hard_disk }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.os }}</td>
     <td>{{ vm.power_status }}</td>
```

In the models.List, there has two thousands of objects, since that it's very slowly in the render layer.
How to speed up the rendering.

The template is used DataTables which is bootstrap's plugin, its auto pagination, but still slowly

This is the code of models.
models.List

```
class List(models.Model):
instance_uuid = models.CharField(verbose_name='UUID', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
list_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='清单主机名', max_length=255, null=True, db_index=True)
hostname = models.CharField(verbose_name='主机名', max_length=255, null=True)
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='IP地址', null=True, db_index=True)
template = models.CharField(verbose_name='是否模板', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
os = models.CharField(verbose_name='操作系统', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
os_version = models.CharField(verbose_name='操作系统版本号', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
total_hard_disk = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='总硬盘容量', blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
cpu = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='CPU核心数量', blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
mem = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='内存', blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
delivery_time = models.DateField(verbose_name='资源交付时间', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
delete_time = models.DateField(verbose_name='资源删除时间', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
tools_status = models.CharField(verbose_name='tools状态', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
guest_status = models.CharField(verbose_name='状态', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
power_status = models.CharField(verbose_name='电源状态', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
esxi_host = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='esxi主机IP', blank=True, null=True)
vc = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='VCenterIP', blank=True, null=True)
app_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='应用名称', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
app_role = models.CharField(verbose_name='应用角色', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
app_description = models.CharField(verbose_name='应用描述', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
app_admin = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name='管理员', to_field='name', null=True, blank=True)
industry_group = models.ForeignKey(IndustryGroup, verbose_name='归属公司', to_field='name', null=True, blank=True)
born_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='创建时间', default=datetime.datetime.now, auto_created=True)
update_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='上次修改时间', auto_now=True, editable=True, blank=True, null=True)
objects = models.Manager()
custom_objs = ListManager()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Vsphere平台虚拟机'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Vsphere平台虚拟机'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.list_name
```

Comment: Paginate them? Cache the page?

Comment: you may add pagination. If you want to load the entire page in one go, there is not other option

Comment: The template is used DataTables which is bootstrap's plugin, its auto pagination, but still slowly

Comment: Rendering even two thousand rows of that simple type shouldn't take long. There must be an other bottle neck. Can you show us the model and give information about your emvironment? Database, machine and so on.